# Band Separation from regular cameras

Tags: classification, land-classification, multi-band

I have removed the IR block filter from a Sony digital compact camera so it has become multispectral (in a way). In addition to that I placed a IR pass filter, so it only captures photos in the Near-Infrared spectrum. I was wondering if there is a way to create 4 different bands (R-G-B-NIR) -instead of the standard 3 RGB bands- by handling the raw files.